# Tableview hiding the sections at first?

Tags: ios, iphone, uitableview

I had  an application in which i am using 10 tableview sections.But i need to put the fifth section of tableview at the top first.then when the user scrolls down only i need to load the first 4 sections.Can anybody guide me on this in iOS?I am using a plain tableview.and i tried

```
[table reloaddata]
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
            NSIndexPath *rowIndexPath = [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:1 inSection:3];
            [self.table scrollToRowAtIndexPath:rowIndexPath atScrollPosition:UITableViewScrollPositionTop animated:YES];
        });
```

but it is only going to 1st row in 1st section .not to the 3rd section.

Answer (score 1):

You can set particular section at the top of tableview In this way:

```
[tableview scrollToRowAtIndexPath:[NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:0 inSection:4] atScrollPosition:UITableViewScrollPositionTop animated:NO];
```

Try this code it may help you.